# Redirect (almost) all requests to the top level url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked at a lot of the other mod_rewrite questions here and tried most of them, but none seem to work for me. This is what I'd like to do.

- Redirect all requests like `http://abc.com/foobar` to `http://abc.com/`
- EXCEPT `images` and `js`, so requests like `http://abc.com/images/foo/bar` or `http://abc.com/js/foo/bar`
- The URL bar should stay the same. So while `http://abc.com/foobar` loads `http://abc.com/`, the URL should read like the former
- Ports should remain intact, so `http://abc.com:8080/foobar` should redirect to `http://abc.com:8080`

This is what I have in my `.htaccess` file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images/.*|js/.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

The condition is working well, and `images` and `js` files are loading fine. I thought the last line would redirect everything else to just the base domain, but I'm still getting 404 errors when I test it out.

I don't want to use a rule like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.com/ [L]
```

because the domain may be different in different deployments.

I think I just have a poor understanding of how this works, but I'm just missing something small. Can someone help me get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/*|/index.html)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^\.]+$ index.html [L]
```

It's not perfect, because the last rule only looks for files without a dot (.) in them. So it will not apply to `http://abc.com/images/image.jpg` but will apply to `http://abc.com/images`.

I don't really understand why I have to do it this way, but it works as it does.